# Generate tex file from lualatex

Tags: luatex, output

Consider the following tex file, which compiles fine with lualatex.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
\begin{luacode}
    px = 0
    py = 0
    qx = 2
    qy = 2
    tex.print("\\draw[ultra thick] (" .. px .. "," .. py .. ") -- (" .. qx .. "," .. qy .. ");" );
\end{luacode}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the file below as an output from a lualatex run which than can be processed with pdflatex? (Of course the `luacode`package is than not needed any more.)

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (2,2);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: in general no (this is like the common question of getting a file with certain macros expanded) the lua code may depend on things that can't be expressed as a fixed tex expression, however for specific cases such as here then you could do something, eg  write to a file rather than to tex then  for pdftex define the luacode environment  to input the relevant file

Comment: thank you. i just thought it would be nice to check what is produced when the lua code is more complicated and have got for instance if statements and other control statements.

Comment: if it is just for debugging you can use `print(....` or `texio.write(...` in addition to the `tex.print(...` so you see the generated tex code